# CakePHP extend model from remote directory

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I'm trying to do something unorthodox. I have 2 cakePHP installations within one directory. Is it possible to extend a model from one of my app installations into another?

This is what my directory structure looks like:

```
app1
  app
    model
      * app1Model
    view
    controller
  libs
  plugins
  ventors

app2
  app
    model
      * app2Model (I want to extent this model with app1Model)
    view
    controller
  libs
  plugins
  ventors
```

I want my app2Model to extend app1Model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sure can! What you're looking for is [`App::build()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#App%3a%3abuild). It allows you to let Cake search other directories when you use `App::uses()`. For example, you could add the additional path to models like so:

```
// assuming your app is under `/var/www`
App::build(array(
  'Model' => array(
    '/var/www/app1/app/model'
  )
));
```

You use `App::build()` to tell Cake "when I use `App::uses()`, look for classes here as well". You would place the code above in your bootstrap file in app2 to tell cake "also look for models in `/var/www/app1/app/model`.

Now in app2, when you use:

```
App::uses('app1Model', 'Model');
```

It will look both in `app2/app/model` and `/var/www/app1/app/model` for models named `app1Model`. You can use `App::build()` to point to other things like controllers and plugins as well, as indicated in the doc.

Beware of conflicting names. From the looks of it, you might want to consider [building a plugin instead](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html#creating-your-own-plugins).

Comment: So how would I use App::build() to extend my model in another app? Sorry, I'm entirely new to cake :)

Comment: No need to apologize, we're all learning! I updated the answer with a brief explanation on how it works.